# Visual Studio Code Live Share on Mac OS 10.11

Tags: visual-studio-code, .net-core, osx-elcapitan

Is there a possibility that Live Share addon in VS Code would be available on 10.11 OS? I've read it's not due to no .NET Core support, but I'm a beginner and I don't know what it means exactly.

Comment: That means unless you upgrade to macOS 10.12 and above, you won't get that feature. .NET Core supported platforms can be found on https://github.com/dotnet/core/blob/master/release-notes/2.0/2.0-supported-os.md

Answer (score 0):

No, because you need to upgrade to macOS 10.12 before you can use this. That is what that means. As for no .NET Core support, that means that there is no support for the popular framework .NET.